# Taxonomy term empty fields in a ALL vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have this "screen" when I click on "manage fields" for all of my taxonomy vocabularies (new included):

[image: empty fields never created]

All these "fields" empty. And I have no these fields.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get what you are asking about . Can you please eleborate ?

Comment: There seems that something funny might have happened with your db and your setup. Did you already have fields there? Can you add a new? If so do you see it?

Comment: @PankajSachdeva ops, I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @PotneySwitters no, I have not these fields. This happen with empty vocabolaries and with new vocabularies. M.

Comment: Try $instances = field_info_instances('taxonomy_term', $vocab_machine_name); dpm($instances); What does this print?

Comment: Please stop adding _thanks_ and signature: Both of them aren't necessary, on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PotneySwitters:  array(0) {
}

Comment: And If I go to "Manage Display" I get this in my log: NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/webmaster/htdocs/MIODOMINIO/modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc on line 1025"

Comment: Something fishy goes on with your installation/code. I can't say where the problem lies, however if I were you I'd go into the function rendering that page, it should be defined in field_ui right?, and debug it :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue caused by the Commerce Services module version 7.x-1.x-dev (25-Apr-2014): https://www.drupal.org/node/2024813